# How to check a non existing element for no visibility in rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, automation, capybara, regression

I have a scenario in which I have table on page which shows 10 records in table. I can get the 10th record by using this xpath:

//tbody[@id='leaderboardGroupAContent']/tr[10]/td[2]

tr[10] is for 10th record. So how can I check that there should be no 11th record? need your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer folks and was simple enough, I used

page.should have_no_selector(:xpath, "//tbody[@id='leaderboardGroupAContent']/tr[11]/td[2]")